# Can I see a file's public URL from inside File Manager?

Tags: file-manager

In EE2 I used to be able to mouse-over a file in File Manager to see its public URL. But in EE5 I only see control panel-based URLs (for edit or download). While I can naturally go into the Edit Upload Directory > Upload Directory, then prefix this to the file name, it would be easier to have the public link somewhere for easy copying. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently but it looks like a method of copying file URL's may be coming in EE6.

Comment: I hope so. I'm not sure why this was taken out.